# Jquery variable assignment not working

Tags: jquery

When I am trying to alert loadpagename it's showing undefined

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('li').click(function() {
        var pagename=$(this).text();

        if(pagename == "home")
        {
            var loadpagename="home.php";
        }

        alert(loadpagename);
        $("#content").load(lodpagename);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar">
   <ul>
     <li>
        home
     </li>
     <li> 
        about us
     </li>
     <li>
        contact
     </li>
   <ul>
 <div id="content">
   dddd
 </div>
```

Comment: If `loadpagename` isn't being set, `pagename` doesn't equal `"home"`.

Comment: fix that too: `$("#content").load(lodpagename);`

Comment: Again -> `var pagename = $.trim( $(this).text() );`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your `li` content contains some spacing characters like tabs and line breaks, so its value isn't **exactly** `"home"`. You can use jQuery's [`trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function to remove these extra spaces and then compare it.

```
var pagename = $.trim($(this).text());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PaAD7/2/

Answer (score 0):

yes `lodpagename` is undefined

use:

```
$("#content").load(loadpagename);
```

instead of:

```
$("#content").load(lodpagename);
                     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo error:
 `$("#content").load(lodpagename);` to  `$("#content").load(loadpagename);`

Working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('li').click(function() {

    var pagename=$(this).text();

    if(pagename == "home")
    {
    var loadpagename="home.php";
    }

    //alert(loadpagename);
        $("#content").load(loadpagename);
     });
     });
</script>


</head>

    <body>
    <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>about</li>
    </ul>
<div id="content">Hello World</div>
      </body>
</html>
```